# Efficient way to draw into a java.awt.graphics object

Tags: java, animation, graphics, rendering, awt

I'm trying to create an animation by dynamically generating frames at each step of the animation. Now as I need to run an algorithm to draw  pixel by pixel the new frame and I'm using a BufferedImage that I access through its raster data. 
However 90% of the time is spent inside java.awt.graphcis.drawImage() that I use to transfer the image into the content of a JFrame.

Is there a more efficient way to draw pixel by pixel inside a graphics object?

Comment: Have you tried java.awt.graphics2D.drawImage(bufferedImage, null, 0, 0)?  I have no idea if it can be more efficient than another draw method... but probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`VolatileImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html). Much faster than that is hard to do..

Comment: Thanks dacwe, it's not clear to me how to use the VolatileImage. Should I keep using the BufferedImage and draw it into the Graphics object from the VolatileImage or should I discard the bufferedImage and draw directly into the volatileimage? I ask it because drawing pixel by pixel using gc.drawLine() or gc.fillRect() seems more computationally expensive than filling the array of the bufferedImage.